# What is the Torah Reading for the Afternoon of Shabbat Chol Hamoed?

Tags: shabbat, torah-reading, mincha-afternoon-prayer, chol-hamoed

When Shabbat occurs on Chol Hamoed of either Sukkot or Passover, the Torah verses Exodus 33:12–34:26 are read in the morning, but what verses are read at the Minchah service in the afternoon?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it is whatever the reading would have been had it been a regular shabbos, so the reading from the next parsha. The reason is that we don't read the Torah by Mincha on holidays (except Yom Kippur) so it is actually a regular Shabbos reading, and not a holiday reading.

Answer (score 0):

My machazor (Rödelheim editions) give the following (Pessach vol. 2, Sukkot vol. 1):

Pessach: *Shemini*, except in a leap-year, where *Acharei-Mot* is read instead

Sukkot: *Vezot haBerachah*

Comment: If it's a leap year that started on a Thursday, most communities read kedoshim

Comment: Maybe worth noting that it’s not the entirety of those parashot but instead a number of verses from their beginnings.